# Injectivity of two sided Laplace transform

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, integration, laplace-transform

Let $\mu,\nu$ be finite Borel measures on $\mathbb R$.
Assume that there is an open interval $(a,b)$ on which the Laplace transforms exist and coincide:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-tx}\,d\mu(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-tx}\,d\nu(x) <\infty
$$
for all $t\in(a,b)$.
Does this imply that $\mu = \nu$?

Comment: Yes. WLOG, $(a,b)=(-2\delta,2\delta)$. Then we have $e^{-\delta|x|}$ integrable with respect to $\mu$ and $\nu$, so we can write the LT of $\mu-\nu$  for complex arguments in the vertical strip around the imaginary axis and it will be analytic there. Being $0$ on $(-\delta,\delta)$, it has to be zero in the whole strip. But on the imaginary axis, it is just the Fourier transform, which determines a finite signed measure on $\mathbb R$ uniquely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are real measures and "exist"
means absolute convergence. Then both transforms can be extended to bounded analytic functions in the strip
$\{ t+i\sigma:a<t<b\}$ and coincide in this trip by uniqueness theorem for analytic functions. But then the restrictions on the line $t=t_0$ for some $t_0\in(a,b)$
can be considered as Fourier transforms of $e^{-t_0x}d\mu(x)$
and $e^{-t_0x}\nu(x)$, therefore by the uniqueness theorem of Fourier transform, these measures coincide, and thus $\mu=\nu$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! Do you know of a reference for this result?